# angular upgrade from 13 to 16

Tags: angular, version, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my angular application from 13.2.0 to 16.00
I am not using selenium-webdriver in my application. When I upgrade it is asking me to install  selenium-webdriver,
when I use gives me an ERROR : npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET repository/npm-group/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-4.0.0.tgz

I am following angular website [link](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=13.0-16.0)

Below is my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.3", 
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "selenium-webdriver":"4.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver":"3.0.22",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",  
    "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `selenium-webdriver` (mostly used for E2E tests) you can remove it from your dependencies with `npm uninstall selenium-webdriver` and `npm uninstall @types/selenium-webdriver`.

Also [selenium 4.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver/v/4.0.0) does exist, so maybe check the rules of your custom registry.